# Nonparameteric Empirical Estimator For Stochastic Process

Tags: estimation, stochastic-processes, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, stochastic-calculus, empirical-bayes

**Motivation:**  If $X$ is a random-variable defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ then Glivenko-Cantelli lemma guarantees that the empirical distribution $\frac1{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \delta_{X^n}\to \mathbb{P}(X\in \cdot)$ (under some mild assumptions) where $X^1,\dots,X^N$ is an i.i.d. sample from $X$.

---

**Question/Reference:**  Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process with values in $\mathbb{R}$ defined on some stochastic basis $(\Omega,\Sigma,(\Sigma_t)_t,\mathbb{P})$ such that $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. continuous and $\sup_{t\geq 0} \mathbb{E}\left[\|X_t\|^2\right]<\infty$.

(When) Is there some type of "empirical estimator" of the conditional law of $X_t$?  In the sense of:
$$
\hat{\nu}^{\Delta:N}:=\frac1{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \delta_{X_{t-n\Delta}-X_{t-(n-1)\Delta}} ;\qquad X_{t_0}=X_s=x
$$
such that $\hat{\nu}^{\Delta:N}\to \mathbb{P}\left(X_t \in \cdot|X_0=x\right)$ as $\Delta \downarrow 0$ and $N\uparrow \infty$ for some "good scaling rate"